# A regular expression for repeated, interleaved copies of a string?

Tags: regex, theory, regular-language

Find a regular expression for this language:

> L = {λ, ab, abac, abacab,abacabac, abacabacab,...}

Ok so I have been working of this problem for sometime now. So far I know that 'ab' repeats its self (ab)*. But I am stumped on 'ac'.... it cant be (ab)*(ac)*...
Any pointers would be appreciated.

I've looked at my book and there is not example that can show me how to solve this.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let's start by simplifying things a bit.  Let's let B denote `ab` and C denote `ac`.  Then you are trying to generate the strings

> λ, B, BC, BCB, BCBC, BCBCB, ...

In this case, you might want to split the regular expression into two cases: one that generates

> λ, BC, BCBC, BCBCBC, BCBCBCBC, ...

and one that generates

> B, BCB, BCBCB, BCBCBCB, ...

The former is given by the regular expression `(BC)*`, and the latter is given by the regular expression `(BC)*B`.  If you combine these together, you get `(BC)* | (BC)*B`, which could be rewritten as `(BC)*(B | λ)`.  All that's left to do is expand this out by replacing `B` and `C with`ab`and`ac`, which gives the resulting regular expression

```
(abac)*(ab | λ)
```

This observation should also let you design a DFA or NFA for the language, but I'll leave that as an exercise. :-)

Hope this helps!